# WCF: How to Customize Error Response

Tags: wcf, json

I am creating a service which communicates with custom made embedded hardware. The code on client side (custom hardware) is written in C and the buffer size for storing received data is limited. The server side is returning JSON object but in case the client sends a wrong request it receives the following:

```
."703"HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

.Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii

.Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0

.Date: Wed, 26 Oct 2011 11:42:06 GMT

.Connection: close

.Content-Length: 326

.

.<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""_http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

.<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>

.<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>

.<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Verb</h2>

.<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request verb is invalid.</p>

.</BODY></HTML>
```

Below are the two methods which return the responses in desired format (JSON) for correct and wrong request:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "StoreData/sid={SessionID}&Data={UserData}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
        public string StoreData(string SessionID, string UserData)
        {
            string ID = DBWorks.StoreUserData(SessionID, UserData);
            return ID;
        }

        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "*", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
        public string GenreateErrorMessage()
        {
            return "error";
        }
```

Is it possible to create a method which would return a short message, for example "invalid verb" instead of the html content in a similar way as GenerateErrorMessage()?

I would appreciate if anyone suggested how to return custom (JSON) content for all bad requests so the client with small buffer would be able to process the content.

On server side the WCF service is hosted in managed application.